# Redirect non-www to www https nginx (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN)

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I just noticed that one of my pages couldn't be accessed on https without `www`

So we I have four different scenarios:

`http://example.com` <- Works

`https://example.com` <- ***Does not work***

`http://www.example.com` Works

`https://www.example.com` Works

The case is that for every request, independent of what above routes you choose, you should allways end on: `https://www.example.com`

I'm not the first having this issue and I tried many scenarios but without any luck (eg. these solutions: [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/624848/redirect-non-www-to-www-over-ssl-with-nginx))

When I try to access `https://example.com` I get a `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`. The certificate is thus only valid for `www.example.com` which makes sense. But I also have another certificate valid for `example.com`.

For know my NGINX setup looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /home/build/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

I've been using NGINX for a while and have actually never noticed, until lately, that I've had that problem.
I know that I could serve the page both with and without `www` and that would solve the problem. But I wish that every interaction should be on `www.example.com` and not without the `www`.

I'm running NGINX version 1.14.0 on a Ubuntu 18.04.

All help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should be interested I solved the issue.

Instead of having multiple certificates I got a wildcard certificate and added the root domain to it as well.

Since LetsEncrypt, as I use in this case, also provides free wildcard certificates all of my sub domains and root domain can use the same certificate instead.

After installing my wildcard certificate my NGINX file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 default_server ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /home/build/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}

server {
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host ~ ^[^.]+\.example\.com$) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404;
}
```

It should be said that the last part of the code is very much inspired by `certbot`'s setup.